# Hibernate query logging - log from entity name

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am using query logging in Hibernate by setting following configuration in my application.properties

```
logging.level.org.springframework.transaction.interceptor=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=DEBUG
```

This works great and logs queries. I need to enhance this logging by adding a table name at the beginning which table am I selecting the data from. E.g. I have following queries logged:

```
2021-06-16 13:11:18.008 DEBUG 6544 --- [io-8080-exec-10] org.hibernate.SQL : select count(program0_.id) as col_0_0_ from public.program program0_ where 1=1
2021-06-16 13:11:18.008 DEBUG 6544 --- [io-8080-exec-10] org.hibernate.SQL : select count(user_0 .id) as col_0_0_ from public.user user_0 where 1=1
```

These queries are simple and it is easy to determine that data is queried from tables `program` and `user`. But in case of big queries a table name at the beginning would ease the examination of logs.

Is there any option how to set this in Hibernate?

Comment: And what if data from multiple tables is selected, what then? Or even no table is even used but a CTE is used, or ... At first, your solution might sound like a good idea, for complex use-cases, it will start to break/deteriorate quickly.

Comment: You always specify one table in 'from' clause so I would like to see the table which is specified there.

Comment: And in case no table is used this field remains empty.

Comment: Well not in the case of a CTE it is just an alias for that query. However without parsing the string and hope that there is a FROM you can trust it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Hibernate doesn't have such an option.
2. The comments already describe that the requirements are rather ill defined, since you can have an arbitrary number of tables in any SQL statement, including 0, so a general solution is rather tricky.
3. But you could do something like this on your own.

   For example if you are using Logback you might register a custom [layout](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html) that parses the message and if it finds a SQL statement it extracts the table out of it.

   Or you could use post process your logs with what ever toolchain you are using to collect and consolidate your logs

Comment: yes, post-processing of logs is an option of course. I was just after something easy to config and use in development environment where logs are just output to console (and not stored in Kibana or some other logs visualizer). So what I was after is an such option in Hibernate - if there's not than it is out of scope.